# simplifying boolean algebra expression

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra

A very urgent question :

Please simplify this logic expression for me with helping boolean algebra :

A'C'D + A'BD + BCD + ABC + ACD'

I know that must use consensus theorem .

my solve :

STEP 1 : Terms 1 & 3 ---eliminate---> Term 2

STEP 2 : Terms 3 & 5 ---eliminate---> Term 4

STEP 3 : Terms 2 & 4 ---eliminate---> Term 3

But truth table said step 3 is incorrect . but why ?

please tell me why step 3 is Wrong ?

and tell me What is the simplest form of it ?